# Number literal with leading zero does not result in expected value

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```js
console.log(066); // 54
```

Why does it log 54, not 66?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, numeric literals that begin with a `0` are treated as octal.

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#Octal_numbers):

> Octal number syntax uses a leading zero. If the digits after the 0 are outside the range 0 through 7, the number will be interpreted as a decimal number.

Answer (score 0):

Because add a prefix `0` will make the number to be considered of base 8([octal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#Octal_numbers)), as way `0x` will make the following number to be of base 16([hexa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#Hexadecimal_numbers))